# Homebrew - bad interpreter: No such file or directory

Tags: ruby, macos, homebrew

Like an idiot, I managed to delete my system ruby install.

I've re-installed xcode, and also installed RVM

Doing this:

```
$ which ruby
```

returns this:

```
/Users/alex/.rvm/bin/ruby
```

However, Homebrew still seems to be broken:

```
$ brew  
-bash: /usr/local/bin/brew: /usr/bin/ruby: bad interpreter: No such file or directory
```

Comment: Can you mark the answer that worked please?

Comment: Fixed a similar issue with another Ruby gem by reinstalling it : `sudo gem install jazzy -n /usr/local/bin`

Comment: This was nothing to do with a Ruby gem

Comment: so what was the solution?

Answer (score 6):

The system ruby on OS X is symlinked to the Ruby.framework.  Since you reinstalled Xcode, it should be installed, but you need to restore the symlinks.

First, check that this file exists and works.

```
$ /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/Current/usr/bin/ruby -v
ruby 1.8.7 (2010-01-10 patchlevel 249) [universal-darwin11.0]
```

If that command works, you should be able to setup the sym links again

```
cd /usr/bin
sudo ln -s ../../System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/Current/usr/bin/ruby /usr/bin/ruby
sudo ln -s ../../System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/Current/usr/bin/erb /usr/bin/erb
sudo ln -s ../../System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/Current/usr/bin/gem /usr/bin/gem
sudo ln -s ../../System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/Current/usr/bin/irb /usr/bin/irb
sudo ln -s ../../System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/Current/usr/bin/rake /usr/bin/rake
sudo ln -s ../../System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/Current/usr/bin/rdoc /usr/bin/rdoc
sudo ln -s ../../System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/Current/usr/bin/ri /usr/bin/ri
sudo ln -s ../../System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/Current/usr/bin/testrb /usr/bin/testrb
```

This should get you started, hopefully I haven't forgotten any of the binaries that need linked.  There are other suggestions to reinstall ruby here: https://superuser.com/questions/171433/is-it-possible-to-reinstall-fix-mac-os-xs-system-ruby-without-doing-a-complete

Another method in a gist: https://gist.github.com/1418384

Comment: Not worked.bogon:bin apple$ sudo ln -s ../../System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/Current/usr/bin/rdoc /usr/bin/rdoc
ln: /usr/bin/rdoc: File exists
bogon:bin apple$ sudo ln -s ../../System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/Current/usr/bin/ri /usr/bin/ri
ln: /usr/bin/ri: File exists
bogon:bin apple$ sudo ln -s ../../System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/Current/usr/bin/testrb /usr/bin/testrb
ln: /usr/bin/testrb: File exists

Comment: Did you forget the else block? "If that command works".  What if ruby don't exist on the specified path?

Answer (score 4):

`brew` is hardcoded to use the system ruby. You could try change `brew`'s shebang (the first line) to `/usr/bin/env ruby`, but it's not guaranteed to work with anything but the system Ruby (I'm not sure it's fully compatible with Ruby 1.9).

Or you could reinstall your system Ruby, which should be possibly by reinstalling OS X.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want to have to reinstall the system ruby, the following should do the trick.

**IMPORTANT:** replace `MY_USER_NAME` with the name of your home folder, which is the "short name" of your user in OS X.

```
sudo ln -s /Users/MY_USER_NAME/.rvm/bin/ruby /usr/bin/ruby
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a new link for Homebrew install

ruby -e "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/master/install)"

Answer (score -2):

Installation link for homebrew has been moved.

Here is the new one:

```
ruby -e "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/master/install)"
```

Answer (score -4):

```
sudo rm -rf /usr/local/Cellar /usr/local/.git
ruby -e "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.github.com/Homebrew/homebrew/go/install)"
```

I solved by reinstall brew.